# SQLite ExecuteReader works from Console and Forms Apps but not from Windows Service

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-services

I have a SQLite data access provider library which just gives non-SQL programmatic access to SQLite Database (.db) through a singleton class. This lib actually uses SQLiteCommands to implement this access. The problem is **SQLiteDataReader's ExecuteReader for a SELECT query works fine with WinForms and Console Test-apps, but gives null while used in Windows Service. Both the Service and Test-apps use the same lib. No Exception is thrown.** Look at the below sample code:

```
private SQLiteConnection slConn = null;
public void Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        slConn = new SQLiteConnection(CreateIQDBConnString(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(GetRegistry(PROJECT_PATH_REG))));
        slConn.Open();
        if (slConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            InitializeTables();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

public List<IIQDevice> GetDevices()
{
    try
    {
        List<IIQDevice> devices = new List<IIQDevice>();

        using (SQLiteCommand r = GetGetDevicesCommand())
        {
            SQLiteDataReader dr = r.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                devices.Add(dr.ToIQDevice());
            }
        }

        return devices;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

private SQLiteCommand GetGetDevicesCommand()
{
    return new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM IQDEVICES;", slConn);
}
```

Comment: This is mostly a user-right problem. I think you have to look in that direction. (try putting it on `Network Services` )

Comment: I tried setting a NetworkService as SeviceAccount, but 1. Still ExecuteReader does not have any data, 2. Now, my ServiceHost for REST Service hosting does not start. However, I am installing this service by "Run As Administrator" InsallUtil, and starting/stopping service using a TrayIcon App with elevated privileges.

Comment: Do you know what is a Windows service? Do you know what is the account used to execute this Windows service? Then for this account do you think it can access the registry key or file system? If you cannot answer the questions yet, try to find the answers for them first and then re-visit this question.

Comment: @ Lex Li, the problem was not with the account, actually my ToIQDevice extension method has a bug, once fixed, the stated problem went away!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the TOIQDevice extension method that I wrote, there was a minor bug in it in once of the SQLiteParameter, once fixed the stated problem went away and now I can see data via ExecuteReader.